# Is there an equivalent to pldd for HP-UX PA-RISC

Tags: hp-ux

On Solaris and HP-UX Itanium, pldd $process_id will give the shared objects loaded for that process. AIX has procldd and Linux has pmap that have the same functionality.

Is there an equivalent for HP-UX PA-RISC?

If not - what approach should be taken to writing one. Use ttrace() maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I believe lsof has the information you're looking for.

http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Sysadmin/lsof-4.84/